# How do I add swarm stickers to a checkin request?

Tags: api, foursquare, swarm

Is there a way to add stickers to a checkin request through the foursquare API? I don't see anything in the documentation. I do see related info in the responses from the users endpoint, checkin history being one example. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add swarm sticker with the **undocument** parameter `stickerId`.

e.g. `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?stickerId= 52a659800000000000000016&...` (Sunny Sticker)

As you know, This parameter is not on [Official document](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add). I can't find sticker list API.

Once again, this parameter is undocument. Use this parameter at your own risk

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answer, where I can found all the stickers ids?